# Custom filter not affecting gtag script position in WordPress footer

Tags: php, plugin-development, hooks

I am using a custom filter to place the gtag script in footer if it is applied in functions.php. The filter code is:

```
if (apply_filters('myplugin_ga_script_position', $position = 'footer')) {
    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
} else {
    add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'myplugin_add_analytics_code'));
}
```

But when I do not use the following filter in functions.php even then the gtag script is in footer:

```
add_filter( 'myplugin_ga_script_position', function( $position ) {
    return 'footer';
});
```

Any fixes?

Comment: why is the value passed to the filter `$position = 'footer'` and not `'footer'` or `$position`? It's best practice to put single statements on single lines rather than combining them like that as it leads to mistakes and cryptic errors. It also doesn't make sense that you're running `apply_filters` in an `if` statement which suggests it will return `true` or `false`, but passing it strings of text instead. Should there be a `=== 'footer'` in the conditional?